# Quiero que solamente tire un mensage box en vez de dos

Tags: c#, windows-forms

```
private void txtExpedienteJudicial_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sql = "select * from Mineria where  ExpedienteJudicial='" + txtExpedienteJudicial.Text + "' ";
            DataTable dt = Funciones.LeerBase(sql);
            if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Ya existe un registro previo.");
                txtAdtvo.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ExpedienteAdmin"].ToString();
                txtConcesionario.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Concesionario"].ToString();
                txtEmpresa.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Empresa"].ToString();
                txtDepartamento.Text = dt.Rows[0]["Departamento"].ToString();

                txtCaja.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existe registro previo");
                txtCaja.Focus();
            }
            string sql1 = "select * from Buscar where  ExpedienteJudicial='" + txtExpedienteJudicial.Text + "'";
            DataTable dt1 = Funciones.LeerBase(sql1);
            if (dt1.Rows.Count != 0)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Pero ya existe un registro previo en la base de datos del cliente.");
                txtAdtvo.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["ExpedienteAdmin"].ToString();
                txtConcesionario.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Concesionario"].ToString();
                txtEmpresa.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Empresa"].ToString();
                txtDepartamento.Text = dt1.Rows[0]["Departamento"].ToString();

                txtCaja.Focus();
            }
            else if (dt1.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No existe registros previos en la base de datos del cliente.");
                txtCaja.Focus();
            }

        }
```

Comment: ¿Has pensado en poner un return después de `txtCaja.Focus()` ??

Comment: es que lo tiene si te fijas. mi problema es que tira dos veces el menssage box y es lo que no quiero

Comment: me refiero a la llamada del focus que tienes tras mostrar el mensaje...

Comment: Claro alfabravo se a lo que apuntas pero necesitaria ayuda en lo del mensage box me podrias ayudar con eso

Comment: Con un return después de tu primer mensaje donde esta el focus con eso haces que se salga del método, y como comentario, deberías de parametrizar tus consultas para evitar  una inyección de SQL